# Gmailr last date in label [gm_label problem]

Tags: r, gmail-api, gmailr

generally i need to get last (the oldest) date of message from each user label.
I have list of id from my search query (today messages) but i cant even get label by gm_label:

```
id (list with all ids that match to search message)
label <- sapply(id, gm_label)
```

OR by simple

```
gm_label(id = "17f87906d3246714")
```

I get error:

```
Error in gmailr_GET(c("labels", id), user_id) : Gmail API error: 404
  Requested entity was not found.
```

gm_labels work fine but i think i need gm_label to my task

Comment: Whenever possible, you need to include a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that reproduces the issue. Also, to disregard any API issues, have you tried getting the messages filtered by that specific ID using [Gmail's Try this API](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.labels/get)?